# limestone module in Nodejs throwing error with nodejs and sphinx

Tags: node.js, sphinx, npm

I have been trying to connect sphinx server with nodejs and limestone module. But it is throwing error as follows. Please help me on this.

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: ENOENT, No such file or directory
    at doConnect (net.js:549:5)
    at Socket.connect (net.js:709:5)
    at Object.createConnection (net.js:265:5)
    at Object.connect (/home/node/node_modules/limestone/limestone.js:129:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/www/bmchat-new/sphinx-connect.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:302:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:430:10)
```

Source code of sphinx-connect.js

```
var limestone = require("limestone").SphinxClient(),
sys = require("sys");

limestone.connect("192.168.2.168:9312", // port. 9312 is standard Sphinx port. also 'host:port' allowed
    function(err) { // callback
      if (err) {
          sys.puts('Connection error: ' + err);
      }

      sys.puts('Connected, sending query');
      limestone.query(
          {'query':'test', maxmatches:1}, 
          function(err, answer) {
          limestone.disconnect();
          sys.puts("Extended search for 'test' yielded " + 
               answer.match_count + " results: " + 
               JSON.stringify(answer));
          });         
     });
```

Comment: Please show us the code of `/home/node/www/bmchat-new/sphinx-connect.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that i am using old limestone.js which i have got from npm(v1.0.106). So the updated one, you can get from [github](https://github.com/kurokikaze/limestone/)

Issue found is, old limestone.js using `server_conn = tcp.createConnection(port);` instead of the below one `server_conn = tcp.createConnection(port, host);`

Comment: Nice catch, you should report an issue for them to release a new version. And you should accept your own answer!

Comment: I tried to accept but it says, "You can accept your own answer tomorrow". :)

Comment: Heh, ok! It's for the best, I guess. :-)